# How do hives generate XP?

Tags: planetside-2

I have a powered Hive, complete with a Core, and it is at 11%. When and how will it generate XP? Also, will it generate XP for me along the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hives don't generate XP. That 11% is how close it is to generating a Victory Point, used to lock a continent.

[Wiki Link](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/hive)

Comment: Does generating a VP give me (or my faction) XP? Presumably locking a continent generates XP for everyone in my faction on that continent?

Answer (score -3):

Hives don't generate XP.
It helps lock the continent, but locking continents don't give XP either.
[Here](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_Points) is a link on all the sources of experience gain